# How do I append a record to start at specific column?

Tags: jquery

I want to append a row on table1 to table2. In table2 I have a checkbox control at column 1, so I want to append the row from table1 to table2 starting at column 2.

This is the piece of jquery code I'm currently using

```
$(".MatchedTransctions tbody tr").click(function () {
  $(this).clone().appendTo("#SelectedForProcessing tbody").closest('tr').children('td').eq(1);
});
```

Below are the two tables. I am trying to insert a row from the first table into the second table, but starting on the second column on table2

```
<div id="MatchedTransctions" class="MatchedTransctions">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Region)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Units)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitCost)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Total)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddedOn)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tbody>
                <tr onclick="toggleClass(this,'selected');">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Region)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Person)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Units)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitCost)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AddedOn)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<table class="table" id="SelectedForProcessing">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Select Record
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Region)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Units)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitCost)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Total)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddedOn)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="SelectedItem" class="SelectedItem" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm not sure what you mean by the above, but I think you saw my post before I could rectify the mistake I made of not including my code.

Comment: Thank you for editing. It would also help to see the HTML of the relevant tables and checkbox too.

Comment: The statement chain `.closest('tr').children('td').eq(1)` at the end seems to have no effect with respect to **appending the `tr`** (the append happens before the rest is executed), so why is it there? Maybe it needs to be rewritten or put in a different spot?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Above is the edited questio with the 2 tables in question.

Comment: @PeterB What I m basically trying to do there is to insert after the first column in table2, which is why I am trying to get the closest 'tr' and the children

Comment: what I am basically trying to do is append a row from table1 into table2, but starting after the column with the checkbox as I will use that for processing each record once added into table2

Comment: I've tried to use insertAfter, insertBefore but they are all not achieving the desired result.

Comment: add an empty column (<td></td>) to the cloned row and you will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do that.

Note that I removed a couple of `td` from the end so the example will not wrap.

```js
$("#MatchedTransctions tbody tr").click(function () {
  var $row = $(this).clone();
  var $td = $('<td />');
  $row.prepend($td);
  $row.appendTo("#SelectedForProcessing tbody");
});
```

```css
#MatchedTransctions{background:lightpink;padding:10px 0;}
#SelectedForProcessing{margin:10px 0;}
td{border:1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MatchedTransctions" class="MatchedTransctions">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    model.Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    model.Region
                </th>
                <th>
                    model.Person
                </th>
                <th>
                    model.Item
                </th>
                <th>
                    model.Units
                </th>
                <th>
                    model.UnitCost
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr onclick="toggleClass(this,'selected');">
                    <td>
                        item.Id
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        item.Region
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        item.Person
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        item.Item
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        item.Units
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        item.UnitCost
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<table class="table" id="SelectedForProcessing">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Select Record
                </th>
                <th>
                    model.Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    model.Region
                </th>
                <th>
                    model.Person
                </th>
                <th>
                    model.Item
                </th>
                <th>
                    model.Units
                </th>
                <th>
                    model.UnitCost
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="SelectedItem" class="SelectedItem" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Not sure where the missing ")" is, but if you click `Full page` *(to the right of* **Hide results**), you will see the example works)

Comment: is there a way in which I can include the checkbox control in the appendTo function? The reason is because I use the checkbox to get the Id of each row when the checkbox is clicked and then I update the database by passing that Id.

Comment: If I declare $td as the following: var $td = $('<td><input type="checkbox" id="SelectedItem" class="SelectedItem" /></td>');....... I'm unable to use the click event on this checkbox

Comment: @ZUKISABHOLOSHA - Hi, just got to work. Go ahead and ask another question and then post the link in a comment here and I'll try to assist - although someone else will probably give the answer first -- *which is why we all love StackOverflow . . .*

Comment: @PeterB Thanks! I was wondering where that missing `)` was. +1

Comment: my question is how can I append the row into a new table but start at column 2... I have a checkbox that gets the Id of each row and passes the id's of all checked records for processing. Currently the function inserts a new row without the checkbox.